# Godot isometric tilemap - get layer of clicked tile

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

I've just started playing around with Godot and I've got an isometric tilemap. I can use different layers to add blocks on top of each other, but what I'm trying to figure out is if there's a way to get the layer of what tile has been clicked.

Ultimately I want to be able to get some data about a clicked tile, but to do that it appears I need to know the layer the clicked tile was on (ignoring those below it for the purpose of clicking). But I also need the layer of this clicked tile to potentially place stuff on top of it. I'm using the below code to get the clicked cell but `get_cell_tile_data` needs the layer and I can't hardcode it obviously!

```
        var clicked_cell = local_to_map(get_local_mouse_position())
        print(clicked_cell)
        var data = get_cell_tile_data(0, clicked_cell)
```

As I say I'm new to Godot, so if there's a different way I should go about getting this please let me know (Not sure if I can use custom data as the same cell type might be on multiple layers and the data method seems to need the layer anyway!)

Comment: The *"current layer"* makes little sense because there can be many tiles at the same coordinates, each having a different layer.

Comment: ok, so when I click on something, that on the isometric tilemap appears to be the top layer, how can I extract that information? I get a clicked_cell in the example above as far as I'm aware so it must think it's hit "something". But at the moment I don't know whether it Godot internally returns my the top layer it's hit based on z-index property of the layers via some sort of raycast. Apologies if that's not conveyed in my question